# Range not writing into Array with VBA UDF...empty even

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having difficulty getting an interpolation function working.  I want it to take a fluid, a variable temperature, and a desired property to return as arguments, and spit out the interpolated property for the temperature given.

I have some arrays set up in the function, but whenever I try to call the Range in the workbook, I get "Empty" for these arrays when I go into debug...

Is there something about UDFs that doesn't allow me to write these properly?  Is there some blatant error I'm missing?

```
Function Interpolate(Seed, Independent, Dependent)

Dim Temperatures() As Variant
Dim Properties() As Variant

Select Case Seed

    Case "Air"

        Temperatures = Array(Worksheets("Air Property Table").Range("A4:A38").Value)

        Select Case Dependent

            Case "Viscosity"

                Properties = Worksheets("Air Property Table").Range("E4:E38").Value

            Case "Thermal Conductivity"

                Properties = Sheets("Air Property Table").Range("F4:F38").Value

            Case "Density"

                Properties = Sheets("Air Property Table").Range("I4:I38").Value

            Case "Specific Heat"

                Properties = Sheets("Air Property Table").Range("B4:B38").Value

        End Select


    Case "Water"

        Temperatures = Sheets("Water Property Table").Range("A4:A19").Value

        Select Case Dependent

            Case "Viscosity"

                Properties = Sheets("Water Property Table").Range("E4:E19").Value

            Case "Thermal Conductivity"

                Properties = Sheets("Water Property Table").Range("F4:F19").Value

            Case "Density"

                Properties = Sheets("Water Property Table").Range("I4:I19").Value

            Case "Specific Heat"

                Properties = Sheets("Water Property Table").Range("B4:B19").Value

        End Select


End Select

For i = LBound(Temperatures) To UBound(Temperatures)

    If Temperatures(i) >= Independent Then

    Output = Properties(i - 1) + (Independent - Temperatures(i - 1)) / (Temperatures(i) - Temperatures(i - 1)) * (Properties(i) - Properties(i - 1))

    Exit For

    End If

Next i



ActiveCell.Value = Output




End Function
```

Comment: Using `Temperatures(i - 1)` in a loop that starts with a value for `i` equal to the `LBound(Temperatures)` is going to cause an error.  (Or do you know that `Temperatures(LBound(Temperatures)) >= Independent` will always be `False`?)

Comment: `ActiveCell.Value = Output` should be `Interpolate = Output` - UDFs can't modify Excel, all they can do is return a value as the result of the function.

Comment: `Temperatures = Array(Worksheets("Air Property Table").Range("A4:A38").Value)` is going to create an array dimensioned `0 To 0`, the single element of which will be an array dimensioned `1 To 35, 1 To 1`.

Comment: I know that I probably wouldn't ever input a value that would be lower than the first entry for the temperatures array, (that would be like -100 C), but I can add an exception.  I'm stumped as to why it fails to write to the Temperatures assignment in the sixth line of code.  I've seen other examples where 'arr = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")' works like a charm, but this doesn't...

Comment: That `Array(....)` is going to just confuse you.  You are creating a single element array, with that single element containing the values from your worksheet.  Get rid of the `Array( )` part.  Then remember that all your variables that you are setting are **two dimensional** arrays (rows x columns) so you should be using something like `Properties(i, 1)` to refer to the ith row and 1st column of `Properties`, etc.

Comment: arr = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").value

Comment: @QHarr The problem with the 6th line is that they are using `Temperatures = Array(something)`, which creates a `0 To 0` array where `Temperatures(0)` therefore contains a `1 To 35, 1 To 1` array.  All the other lines are being written correctly, but that one line is just .... wrong.

Comment: Thanks! The addressing of the array with two indices (despite being a one dimensional array) was the issue.